# Overload resolution with enable_if

Tags: c++, sfinae, overload-resolution, enable-if

Recently, I was asked this question on an interview:

> Which Vector constructor will be called in the code below?
>
> ```cpp
> #include <iostream>
>
> class Iterator {
> public:
>   Iterator(int &x): ptr_(&x) {} 
>
> private:
>   int* ptr_ = nullptr;
> };
>
>
> template<class T>
> class Vector {
> public:
>     Vector(size_t size, T default_value) {
>       std::cout << "Constructor #1 called\n";
>     }
>
>     template<class Iterator>
>     Vector(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
>       std::cout << "Constructor #2 called\n";
>     }
> };
>
>
> int main() {
>   auto v = Vector<int>(3, 5);
>
> }
> ```

The answer is the second constructor, because the types are the same. I do not really understand the reason. Could anybody explain why that happens?

Also, the second part of the question was to use `std::enable_if` so that the first constructor would be called instead. What is the way to accomplish this?

Comment: As a hint: the `Iterator` typename is a red-herring. It could just be named e.g. `U`. So you have one constructor `Vector<T>::Vector(std::size_t, T)` and another `Vector<T>::Vector<U>(U, U)`, with `T` and `U` both filled in as `int` at the instantiation in `main`

Comment: The 1st constructor will be be `Vector(size_t, int)` and the second deduced to be `Vector(int, int)`.  The 2nd is an exact match.

Comment: @Brian Oh... I wasn't attentive enough. Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the 1st part:

`3` and `5` are literals of type `int`.

In the 1st constructor, the 2nd parameter is using the template argument named `T`, which `main()` is specifying explicitly as `int`, so `5` can be passed as-is. However, `size_t` is an implementation-defined unsigned type, thus not `int`, so an implicit conversion (ie, integer promotion) is required in order to pass `3` to the 1st parameter.

On the other hand, the 2nd constructor uses a template argument named `Iterator` for both of its input parameters, and that template argument is being *deduced* as `int` in this example, so no implicit conversion is needed.  Both `3` and `5` can be passed as-is, so the 2nd constructor is an *exact match* for `Vector<int>(3, 5)`.

If the 2nd constructor had intended to use the `class` named `Iterator` instead for its input parameters, then the template argument on the 2nd constructor is unnecessary and should be removed, eg:

```
template<class T>
class Vector {
public:
    Vector(size_t size, T default_value) {
      std::cout << "Constructor #1 called\n";
    }

    Vector(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
      std::cout << "Constructor #2 called\n";
    }
};
```

In which case, the 1st constructor becomes a *better* match for `Vector<int>(3, 5)`. Even though the `Iterator` class can be constructed from an `int` variable, overload resolution prefers integer promotion over object construction. Also, because `3` and `5` are rvalues, and a non-const `int&` reference can't bind to an rvalue, so the `Iterator` class wouldn't be constructable in this example anyway.

Comment: This is very helpful. Now I see that I have to use ```enable_if<!is_same<Iter, int>>``` to call the 1st constructor instead.

Answer (score 1):

To do part 2, it is sufficient to rewrite the second constructor in the following way:

```
     template<typename Iterator, 
          typename = std::enable_if_t< !std::is_same_v <Iterator, int> >>
     Vector(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
       std::cout << "Constructor #2 called\n";
     }
```

Comment: You might want to use [std::is_integral_v](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral) to be a bit more general, so it also works for a few types other than `int`.